# Object inheritance with EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance

I've frequently facing that there is a problem to get access to the parent's variable if these object are inherited from one parent.

For example there are `Group` and `Course`, both of them are inherited from `Community` and have same field `Owner` and collection of `Post`'s. But we need to access `post.Community.Owner`.

What is the proper way to create code first architecture, related to this issue by using EF API or data annotations?

```
class Community
{
    public int Id {get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual User Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

class Group : Community {}


class Course: Community {}
```

And we need to call:

```
var User = post.Community.Owner;
```

Comment: Added a code sample that briefly explains my situation

Comment: Does `Post` have a `virtual` `Community` property?  The usage and structure implies that it could/should.